How to reach multiple websites in same docker by URL without having to edit my hosts-file
I have a Windows 11 machine that I use run the Docker Engine. One of my docker containers is an Apache-container with PHP.
I want to run multiple websites in this container. In order to tell Apache which site a user is requesting from the browser, I use a servername entry in my Apache conf files that are copied into the DOcker container.
e.g.:
ServerName site1.docker

ServerName site2.docker

In order to tell my Windows system how to reach the Docker container I edit my Hosts file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) and add these URLs:
  127.0.0.1 site1.docker site2.docker

However, everytime I add a new site I need to remember to add this URL to the hosts file. Is there a better solution, e.g. some entry in the docker-compose of docker files?
Thank you!

Can you set up your reverse proxy to use path-based routing instead, so http://localhost/site1 and http://localhost/site2 go to different services internally?

I do not have a reverse proxy; at least not as far as I know.

The Apache httpd is acting as a reverse proxy here, accepting HTTP connections from outside and forwarding them to the back-end services.

First, services like sslip.io exist. These services maintain wild carded dns that either returns localhost, or an ip of your choice and mean you can use names like http://site1.localtest.me or http://site1.127-0-0-1.sslip.io as aliases for localhost.
Next. A reverse proxy. Add Caddy or Traefik to your compose file. Reverse proxies use the request fields - such as host header - and a set of rules - to determine where the request should be handled.
This example uses Traefik to listen on port 80. Traefik then scans containers for labels to match requests.
services:
  ingress:
    image: traefik:v3.2
    command: |
      --api.insecure
      --providers.docker
    networks:
      - www
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 80:80
    labels:
      traefik.http.routers.ingress.rule: HostRegexp("traefik.*")
      traefik.http.services.ingress.loadbalancer.server.port: 8080

  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      - www
    labels:
      traefik.http.routers.web.rule: HostRegexp("web.*")

networks:
  www:

You can use http://traefik.127-0-0-1.sslip.io or http://web.localtest.me or similar hostnames in the browser.
Traefik (or Caddy) does not have to run in the same compose file - they just need to share a docker network with any services they are handling traffic for.

I'll have a look at it!
